# How to push & merge specific commit history?

Tags: git, perforce, git-merge, git-push, git-p4

I cloned a Repo from Perfoce into Git locally with all its history, call it `SubProj`, and then I pushed it to a remote repo, and used that remote repo to merge `SubProj` under a `SuperProj`.

There is no way to import part of the history from Perforce to Git, either [`@all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4#_clone) or `none`. Anyway, It went fine and I deleted the local repo, and its remote.

Now, there are changes on the Perforce depot `SubProj`, so I cloned `SubProj` again with all the history, I want to push then merge with `SuperProj` but I do not want the whole history (only the new changes).

Say `SubProj` has this history, and it is local:

> A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H

I know we can push starting from the oldest commit, and until a [specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17826826/6540193). Ex:

```
git push SubProjRemote <commit C on master>:master
```

Will push `A--B--C` to the remote.

But:

Can I push only `E--F--G--H` to the remote repo?

Can I push all, but then merge only `E--F--G--H`?

Comment: Are the SHA-1 hashes of the two clones from Perforce identical? With other word, when you migrated again is the hash of `E` the same as it was on the first Migration in the remote repo?

Comment: @milbrandt I can't verify that, I deleted the repo of the first clone. Now I only have the second clone and it is the whole history as a Git repo. But I know from which date (what commit) I want to start with (Ex `E--F--G--H`).

Comment: You only deleted it locally. The remote repo of the first migration still exist, doesn't it?

Comment: @milbrandt No, I deleted both local and remote. I will remove this comment because I had this on OP

Comment: Your remote project is `SuperProj`. At least is you didn't do a squash commit, all commits of the original `SubProj` should be included there.

Comment: @milbrandt oh I see, you are correct, I see the whole history of `SubProj` under `SuperProj`. Last commit there was `6fddcf25`. So, from the new clone, I want only the stuff after `6fddcf25`. But, this key commit has a different SHA-1 on the current clone (`a69f1577`)

Comment: That was the information I asked. Corresponding commits of the migratation have different SHA-1 hashes. The commit `6fddcf25` was the commit before the merge, wasn't it? If it was the merge, please double check for the parents, if one of them has the hash `a69f1577`. If this is the case, it will be easy. Otherwise we have to go the cumbersome way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge a specific section of a branch into another branch, you can use rebase's onto feature. Once you are on the branch with the commits you want + the extra commits, you can run:

git rebase --onto < branch_to_rebase_off_of > < commit_to_stop_before > < first_commit_to_include >

For your example taking commits E through H but not A-D, you can run the following, substituting the commit hash for D and H:

git rebase --onto other_branch D H

The branch should now have the base of other_branch, but it should have also applied commits E through H. You can then push this branch wherever it needs to go.